# Why doesn't the .grid feature work in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBjFN.png)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('1000x500')

one = Label(root, text='this is not row 5 or column 6!')
one.grid(row=5, column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: btw, I am a beginner at python, so sorry if its a dumb mistake. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that this is not row 5, column 5? Since there is nothing in the other rows, why can't they have zero width and height? How did you expect it to look, and why?

Comment: As mentioned in [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), the Tkinter grid ignores empty rows and empty columns.

Comment: It's working as defined.